# VScode opens three empty files named "visual", "studio", and "code"

Tags: visual-studio-code

I open a file on a BeagleBone Black running debian 8.4 with VScode via SFTP with winSCP. By right clicking > edit > code.

When the file opens, VScode also opens three new files named visual, studio, and code (image attached). I did not create these files myself. Opening files from other sources does not cause this.

[image]

I have tried closing the files individually. Connecting and reconnecting. Opening and closing VScode. In every possible order and configuration. They return every time when opening another file with the same method.

This is how I have set up VScode as an editor in WinSCP.

[image][image]

This is extremely odd, and only trivial, yet highly annoying.

What's causing this? How do I stop it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VS Code opens "VS" and "code" window every time i open a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71250763/vs-code-opens-vs-and-code-window-every-time-i-open-a-file)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I do this:

1. Edit position "Code"
2. Select "Associated aplication" and click OK
3. Again: Edit, select "External editor" and type "C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" (on my PC VS Code is installed for all user)

After this restart Winscp and that's it, it works for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).